# Left join pandas if column value is within a certain range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join

I was wondering if it were possible to merge two datasets if the values were in a certain range of each other.

For example, If I want to join on zip codes, then an exact match isn't required and the join takes place if the left table zip code is within a range of 15 from the right table zip code.

Here is some example data and a diagram to make this clear.

```
# Create sample dataframe

data1 = [[10001, 'NY'], [10007, 'NY'], [10013, 'NY'], [90011, 'CA'], [91331, 'CA'], [90650, 'CA']]

data2 = [[10003, 'NY', 1200], [10008, 'NY', 1460], [10010, 'NY', 1900], [90011, 'CA', 850], [91315, 'CA', 1700], [90645, 'CA',2300]]

df_left = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Zip', 'State'])
df_right = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Zip', 'State', 'Average_Rent'])

print(df_left.head())
print(df_right.head())

# Merge
df_merge = df_left.merge(df_right, left_on='Zip', right_on = 'Zip', how='left')
print(df_merge)

# Want to merge if within a 5 zipcode radius. If two zips nearby, then choose the first observation.
data3 = [[10001, 'NY', 10003, 12000], [10007, 'NY', 10008, 1460], [10007, 'NY', 10010, 1900], [10013, 'NY', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
         [90011, 'CA', 90011, 850], [91331, 'CA', 'NaN', 'NaN'], [90650, 'CA', 90645, 2300]]

df_want = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns = ['Zip_left', 'State', 'Zip_right', 'Rent'])
df_want.head(6)
```

The result of this is shown below:

[image]

A traditional left join will leave me with the top result, whereas the result I am after is shown in the bottom (not concerned about what columns are output, I just input them on the spot).

The main rule I want to enforce is the interval merge. For the tie-breaker this example chooses the first one, but even if the zip code 10010 from the right table gets matched twice: once to 10007 and once to 10013, that's not an issue. Quite frankly the tie-breaker rule doesn't bother me, as long as at least one merge is made.

Comment: @sammywemmy sorry, typo regarding the 1200/12000. For 10013 I just had some arbitrary tie-breaker in mind, but I quite like what enke has done in their answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pandas 1.2.0., you can cross `merge`, which creates the cartesian product from the two DataFrames. So cross merge and filter the columns where the states match. Then find the absolute difference between the zip codes and use it to identify the rows where the distance is the closest for each "Zip_left". Finally, `mask` the rows where the difference is greater than 15 (even if the closest), so we fill them with NaN:

```
merged = df_left.merge(df_right, how='cross', suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
merged = merged[merged['State_left']==merged['State_right']]
merged['Diff'] = merged['Zip_left'].sub(merged['Zip_right']).abs()
merged = merged[merged.groupby('Zip_left')['Diff'].transform('min') == merged['Diff']]
cols = merged.columns[~merged.columns.str.endswith('left')]
merged[cols] = merged[cols].mask(merged['Diff']>15)
out = merged.drop(columns=['State_right','Diff']).rename(columns={'State_left':'State'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Zip_left State  Zip_right  Average_Rent
0     10001    NY    10003.0        1200.0
1     10007    NY    10008.0        1460.0
2     10013    NY    10010.0        1900.0
3     90011    CA    90011.0         850.0
4     91331    CA        NaN           NaN
5     90650    CA    90645.0        2300.0
```

Comment: Hello enke, I actually tried this out recently and got a memory error:
"MemoryError: Unable to allocate 41.6 GiB for an array with shape (11, 507271853) and data type int64".
Im guessing this is because the cartesian product between a few thousand zip codes is too huge? Is there an alternative you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

One option is [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which tries to avoid a cartesian join, and improve memory performance.

I also borrow from enke's solution (He grasped your question way better than I could):

```py
# install latest from dev
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor
```

Create boundaries for start and end, for df_right

```py
df_right = (df_right
            .assign(
                start = df_right.Zip - 15, 
                end = df_right.Zip + 15)
            .rename(columns = {'Zip':'Zip_right', 
                               'State':'State_right'})
            )
```

Compute [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
out = (df_left
      .conditional_join(
          df_right,
          ('State', 'State_right', '=='),
          ('Zip', 'start', '>='),
          ('Zip', 'end', '<='),
          how = 'left')
      .assign(diff_ = lambda df: df.Zip.sub(df.Zip_right).abs())
       )
```

Get the rows with the minimum `diff_`:

```py
(
out
# you can get better performance
# if you skip the sort
# and just grab the fist match
.sort_values(['Zip', 'diff_'])
.groupby('Zip', sort = False)
.nth(0)
.loc[:, ['State', 'Zip_right', 'Average_Rent']]
.reset_index()
)

     Zip State  Zip_right  Average_Rent
0  10001    NY    10003.0        1200.0
1  10007    NY    10008.0        1460.0
2  10013    NY    10010.0        1900.0
3  90011    CA    90011.0         850.0
4  90650    CA    90645.0        2300.0
5  91331    CA        NaN           NaN
```